# how to avoid Files.lines() throwing MalformedInputException on japanese text?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

My code throws the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:590)
```

when executing this line

```
Files.lines(in.toPath()).forEachOrdered(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String s) {
        //stuff
    });
```

the file that causes this behaviour when opened in notepad++ it shows like this
[image]

of course the text is garbled because of the encoding, if i select "Convert to UTF-8" from the "Encoding" menu then it shows correctly

[image]

which makes me assume UTF-8 is the correct encoding, however according to Java documentation Files.lines() uses UTF-8 encoding by default (it's the equivalent of  Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) yet it still breaks when reading files with japanese text, how should i handle this?

Comment: May be your file contains [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: The file could be in UTF-8 or another Japanese encoding.

Comment: I have similar issue. In debugger I found what causes it. `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer` representation contains character with value `-45` (for input string `MÓDULOS`). then `sun.nio.cs.UTF_8` throws exception cause `isNotContinuation` test failes. test is `return (var0 & 192) != 128;`. I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the content of the file after "Convert to UTF-8" in notepad++?

`Convert to UTF-8` in notepad++ **doesn't** mean "Re-open and read the content of the file as it is encoded in UTF-8 and save it immediately", so you have to save the file explicitly.

When I make a file `C:\tmp\inFile.txt` like this and save it in **Windows-31J** encoding:

```plaintext
*-------- HEADER FIELD

# PLAYER 1
# TITLE 水晶世界 ～Fracture～[BLACK]
# BPM 180
```

And I make a test program like this:

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class TestForEachOrdered {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        File in = new File("C:/tmp/inFile.txt");
        Files.lines(in.toPath()).forEachOrdered(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

I've got the following exception. It looks the same in the problem.

```plaintext
1.8.0_202
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:590)
    at org.example.TestForEachOrdered.main(TestForEachOrdered.java:13)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:571)
    ... 4 more
```

After I **explicitly saved** the file in UTF-8, I got the following result:

```plaintext
1.8.0_202

*-------- HEADER FIELD

# PLAYER 1
# TITLE 水晶世界 ～Fracture～[BLACK]
# BPM 180
```